# How to handle form-submission based on a radio-button value in a validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

How to handle form-submission, based on a radio-button value?

```
 if (jQuery(this).attr("value") == "accept")
```

then it should show a div and after that enable form submission

```
 if (jQuery(this).attr("value") == "reject")
```

then form submit button will be disabled

**How to do it in validation plugin?**